# Scaling a UIView from the center of a pinch gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, zooming, multi-touch

I am having an issue with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and scaling a `UIView`.  Due to the requirements of the application, I basically need to reverse engineer the functionality of embedding a `UIView` inside of a `UIScrollView` and zooming in that way.

Essentially, what I want to accomplish is that when I scale (aka zoom) the view it will scale towards the position of the midpoint of the pinch rather than scale directly from the center.  Has anyone had experience with this type of transform on a `UIView`?

Note: Using a `UIScrollView` is **NOT AN OPTION** for this.